# $Y=AX + BX^3$. Compute Var(Y|X=x) $X$ has distribution $N(1,1)$ and $A$ & $B$ both have distribution $U(-1,1)$.

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, correlation

$Y=AX + BX^3$, $X$ has distribution $N(1,1)$ and $A$ & $B$ both have distribution $U(-1,1)$. $X,A, B$ are all independent. May assume without proof that X and Y are jointly continuous and that $B$ and $X^k$ are independent for all $k \in \Bbb N$. How do I compute $Var(Y|X=x)$? (In previous parts of the question I was asked to show $E[Y|X] = 0$, compute $E[Y]$, which I showed was $0$, and compute $corr(X,Y)$ which I also showed was $0$). Please point me in the right direction with an appropriate hint. (Could I also check my answer once computed to check my understanding?) Thanks.

Comment: Can you write down the formula for $E(Y^2|X=x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Var(A)=Var(B)=\frac{(1-(-1))^2}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Now, intuitively,

$\begin{align}Var(Y|X=x) &= & Var(AX+BX^3|X=x)\\&=&Var(Ax+Bx^3)\\&=&x^2Var(A)+(x^3)^2Var(B)\\&=&\frac{x^2+x^6}{3}\end{align}$.

Can you formalize the idea?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - would this not be sufficient as the answer? What needs to be formalised?

Comment: Well that depends on how formal you want to write. For example, justify the independence of A and B so that the variance separates the sum, and that the constants are squared

Comment: Ah, okay I see - thank you! Is it possible to conclude that X&Y are independent or dependent from this result?

Comment: Yes, but more in general. If $X,A,B$ are all independent and you apply the borel-measurable functions $f_1(x,a,b)=x$ and $f_2(x,a,b)=ax+bx^3$ to the random vector $(X,A,B)$, you obtain independent variables.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been taught about measure theory. Is there a simpler way to come to the conclusion that X and Y are dependent or not from the value of Var(Y|X=x)?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent (with my previous argument). But you can never justify independence with conditional expectation. If the covariance had given different from 0 there you could say that they were NOT independent.

Comment: Do you understand what I said? In general, you will be able to use these arguments to prove that they are NOT independent. But when the covariance is 0 (which does not ensure independence), we must go another way.